# python dictionary autoescapes forward slash

Tags: python, regex

I have a class, and in this class I want to store a variable that contains a regular expression. In this case something to identify an IP address:

```
class Foo:
'''a class to parse through an sosreport and begin the cleaning process required in many industries'''

def __init__(self, somefile):

    self.version = '0.1'
    self.somefile = somefile
    self.network_search = {'strings':('foo','bar','foobar','barfoo',), 'regex':"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})"}
```

Unfortunately, when I call the variable from a prompt I get this:

```
>>> a = Foo('sosreport')
>>> a.network_search['regex']
'(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})'
```

Is it possible to do this? Is there a better way? I've tried single and double quotes, but can't think of a way around it.

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? Forward slashes (`\ `) need to be escaped in python as the are control characters. Its messy, but when a string is returned it comes back in a safe format, so `\ ` becomes `\\ `.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Not really, in that question the issue was the file didn't exist.

Comment: Well it's a duplicate of *something*; someone gets this wrong at least once a month.

Comment: simple try ```print '(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})'```
this returns ```(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})```

Comment: To be pedantic, you're talking about *back*slashes: `\ ` ; forward slashes lean forwards: `/`. Sorry - pet peeve of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion here is between regexes proper and strings.
You build a regex from a string, and if you print a regex (as you are implicitly doing; well, technically you're not actually printing, but getting a string representation) then you get a string. The string has to show the backslashes as escaped, but the regex's internal representation is actually doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

apparently it works anyway...

```
>>> a = Foo('somefile')
>>> a.network_search['regex']
'(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})'
>>> import re
>>> string1 = 'ip addy is 192.168.1.153 so there'
>>> x=a.network_search['regex']
>>> m = re.search(x,string1)
>>> if m:
...   print your IP matches
... 
your IP matches
>>> string2 = 'no ip addy so there'
>>> n = re.search(x,string2)
>>> if n:
...   print "your IP matches"
... 
>>>
```